# How I can write to particular tag in XML?

Tags: java, xml

I have such structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
        <command> Check title (Total posts,Total topics,Total members,Our newest member)
         <result> -// I need to write here something//- </result>
        </command>
        <command> Check login 
         <result>  </result>
        </command>
       </config>
```

I need to write value in the first result tag, how can i do it?

Comment: What you have till now? Any code or just this post?

Comment: Well what XML API are you using, and what have you tried? You should attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking, and then explain what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can answer questions directly without further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NodeList list = yourNodeList.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

     Node node = list.item(i);
     if ("result".equals(node.getNodeName())) 
     {
        node.setTextContent("your_value");
     }
}
```

Also, take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/). Google is full of examples ; )

Answer (score 0):

Below example will help you to put value into `result` tag.

```
//xmlDoc is Document
result = xmlDoc.createElement("result");
result.appendChild(xmlDoc.createTextNode("<your value here...>"));
command.appendChild(result);
```